# Why can't my Flash helper process create a logfile in AppData\LocalLow?

Tags: winapi

The following code is failing from inside a sandboxed plugin, according to Process Monitor the error is ACCESS_DENIED.

```
::PathCchAppend(logDirectory, _MAX_PATH, L"xxxxxxxx.log");
logFile = ::CreateFileW(logDirectory, FILE_GENERIC_READ | FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nullptr, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
```

The `WCHAR logDirectory[_MAX_PATH+1]` variable contains the correct path, confirmed with Process Monitor (no funniness with unescaped paths).

`icacls` proves that the mandatory access label for low integrity is present on the directory

```
C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData>icacls LocalLow
LocalLow NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
         BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
         XXXXXXXXXXXX:(OI)(CI)(F)
         Mandatory Label\Low Mandatory Level:(OI)(CI)(NW)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Isn't the AppData\LocalLow directory the right place for logging from low integrity (sandboxed) code?  What can cause this to fail?

This code is loaded into a Flash plugin, actually.  Does Flash's sandboxing layer deny even more filesystem access than normal for a low integrity process?  [It says](http://blogs.adobe.com/security/2012/06/inside-flash-player-protected-mode-for-firefox.html)

> We identified that our sandbox process will need to access OS resources using the following SIDs: BUILTIN\Users, Everyone, the User’s Logon SID, and NTAUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE. For any other SIDs that are inherited from the user, we set the deny-only attribute to prohibit the process from accessing the resource based solely on that SID.

It's the "User's Logon SID" that should be granting access to this location, right?

I've even created the logfile in advance, verified using `icacls` that it has the low integrity label, and `CreateFile` still fails.